# Publishing DataFrame to Kafka

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I encounter a very trivial problem, but currently, I can't find solution.

Assuming I have a spark DataFrame, it could be untyped or strongly typed, does not really matter.

Now I want to publish it to Kafka, the following code works great:

```
df2.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING) as key", "CAST(value AS STRING) as value")
      .write.format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host:9092")
      .option("topic", "test").save()
```

However, I wish to publish using a more complex sterilizer- in my case a custom one.

How can I do it? In other words, instead of publishing strings, I wish to publish an object.

My data source is Vertica, and I'm using [Vertica connector](https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.2.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SparkConnector/LoadingVerticaDataToSparkUsingVerticaDataSource.htm) to consume events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [foreachPartition](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#foreachPartition-scala.Function1-) to publish data to a external source in a custom way. In this way you will create only one connection for each partition instead of record if you using foreach.